# Error in inflating class fragment after sending app in background and reopening

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

My app works fine when used first time. But when I send it in background for a long and reopening its showing error in  inflating class fragment. I did google found that its because of inflating a fragment without UI but I am able to resolve the problem. 
My logcat is as follow

```
09-03 11:55:51.219: E/AndroidRuntime(23789): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-03 11:55:51.219: E/AndroidRuntime(23789): Process: com.hundredpercentile.vidyamandirclasses, PID: 23789
09-03 11:55:51.219: E/AndroidRuntime(23789): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.hundredpercentile.vidyamandirclasses/com.hundredpercentile.vidyamandirclasses.test_engine.activity.TestSectionActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #91: Error inflating class fragment
09-03 11:55:51.219: E/AndroidRuntime(23789):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2198)
09-03 11:55:51.219: E/AndroidRuntime(23789):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
09-03 11:55:51.219: E/AndroidRuntime(23789):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
09-03 11:55:51.219: E/AndroidRuntime(23789):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
09-03 11:55:51.219: E/AndroidRuntime(23789):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
09-03 11:55:51.219: E/AndroidRuntime(23789):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
09-03 11:55:51.219: E/AndroidRuntime(23789):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
09-03 11:55:51.219: E/AndroidRuntime(23789):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
09-03 11:55:51.219: E/AndroidRuntime(23789):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
09-03 11:55:51.219: E/AndroidRuntime(23789):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
09-03 11:55:51.219: E/AndroidRuntime(23789): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #91: Error inflating class fragment
09-03 11:55:51.219: E/AndroidRuntime(23789):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
09-03 11:55:51.219: E/AndroidRuntime(23789):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
09-03 11:55:51.219: E/AndroidRuntime(23789):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
09-03 11:55:51.219: E/AndroidRuntime(23789):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
09-03 11:55:51.219: E/AndroidRuntime(23789):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
09-03 11:55:51.219: E/AndroidRuntime(23789):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
09-03 11:55:51.219: E/AndroidRuntime(23789):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
09-03 11:55:51.219: E/AndroidRuntime(23789):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1937)
09-03 11:55:51.219: E/AndroidRuntime(23789):    at com.hundredpercentile.vidyamandirclasses.test_engine.activity.TestSectionActivity.onCreate(TestSectionActivity.java:151)
09-03 11:55:51.219: E/AndroidRuntime(23789):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5248)
09-03 11:55:51.219: E/AndroidRuntime(23789):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1110)
09-03 11:55:51.219: E/AndroidRuntime(23789):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2162)
09-03 11:55:51.219: E/AndroidRuntime(23789):    ... 9 more
09-03 11:55:51.219: E/AndroidRuntime(23789): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment com.hundredpercentile.vidyamandirclasses.test_engine.fragment.TestEngineQuestionFragment did not create a view.
09-03 11:55:51.219: E/AndroidRuntime(23789):    at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4826)
09-03 11:55:51.219: E/AndroidRuntime(23789):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
09-03 11:55:51.219: E/AndroidRuntime(23789):    ... 20 more
```

My activity inflate fragment using class in XML

```
<fragment
            android:id="@+id/view_test_section"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/view_header"
            class="package.Fragment"
            android:background="@color/white" />
```

Comment: which line is XML line no. 91?

Comment: @maven
its stating of fragment 
<fragment

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect some object needed by the TestEngineQuestionFragment is being garbage collected while the application is backgrounded causing an exception during inflation. Try adding a *lot* of Debug.Log statements in your fragment onCreateView to see if you can narrow down where it might be happening. I'd be looking very closely at any custom views used in the fragment layout too.

Good luck.

Comment: I think onCreateView() of fragment is not being called
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment com.hundredpercentile.vidyamandirclasses.test_engine.fragment.TestEngineQuestionFragment did not create a view.

Comment: sorry onCreateView() is being called